# Instalação do SQL Server no cliente

Tags: sql, sql-server

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em C#, que usa o SQL Server Express 2012. No desenvolvimento tudo correu bem com os acessos à base de dados porque está tudo na mesma maquina ( utilizo o `localhost`).

Agora tenho de instalar a aplicação noutros computadores. A base de dados é local. Que versão do SQL tenho de instalar nesses computadores e qual a forma mais fácil de o fazer dado que não serei eu a fazer a instalação?     Será o localDB uma opção?
Connection string - `"Data Source=localhost ; Initial Catalog = scalnet ; Integrated Security=SSPI; Trusted_Connection=Yes";`
No computador que estou a desenvolver a app estou a utilizar o SQL Server 2012 (que tem o server como localhost) Será que é este o problema?..

EDIT :: Mudei a connection string para `"Data Source=.\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog = scalnet ; Integrated Security=SSPI; Trusted_Connection=Yes"`
Na outra maquina já não parece aquele erro mas sim quando faço o restore..
Agora aparece um erro quando tento fazer o restore da base de dados

```
 using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(config))
             {
                 conexao.Open();
                 string sqlR = "ALTER DATABASE " + nomeDB + " SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; ";
                 sqlR += "USE master RESTORE DATABASE " + nomeDB + " FROM DISK = '" + restoreDB + "'WITH REPLACE;";
                 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlR, conexao);
                 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 MessageBox.Show("Base de Dados Restaurada");
             }
```

Comment: Olá. A versão a instalar no cliente vai ser na mesma o SQL Server Express 2012. Pode sempre optar por fazer a instalação sem os `Management Tools`, de forma a reduzir o tamanho da instalação. Existe alguma restrição na instalação para estar a fazer a pergunta?

Comment: A única restrição seria mesmo o espaço a ocupar e tb o sistema operativo da maquina onde vai ser instalado pois sei que no win xp o server 2012 não é compativel. Teria de instalar o 2008 R2..

Comment: Nesse caso terá de garantir que o código da base de dados é compatível com 2008 R2. Mencionou C#, tenha em atenção que o Windows XP só suporta até à .Net Framework 4.0 .

Comment: Sim, tomei atenção a isso. Obrigada. Ao sugerir para não instalar os Management Tools, o cliente fica sem acesso direto à base de dados certo? O software usa o SQL Server mas o cliente não consegue digamos "editar". é isso?

Comment: Sim, vai ficar sem possibilidade de usar o editor do SQL para editar a base de dados. No entanto isso deverá ser controlado com as contas e não por omissão de ferramentas, dado que é possível que o cliente instale posteriormente os `Management Tools`.

Comment: Mas se o cliente tem acesso a um usuário Administrador no seu computador ele pode entrar no SQL pela autenticação do Windows e assim alterar o que quiser. Garantir que o usuário não vá alterar nada na base de dados só é possível se o cliente não tiver acesso ao servidor em que o SQL está instalado.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade a "solução" inicial para o problema do Administrador é não ter os `Management Tools`. Mas tal como referi, a solução ideal é configurar os `logins` de forma a garantir que só as pessoas certas conseguem editar os dados. Pode por exemplo desabilitar o `login` com credenciais do Windows e usar apenas a conta `sa`.

Comment: Ok. já instalei o SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2012 numa maquina de testes com o win7. AParece o erro quando tento executar o programa "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connectionto SQL SERVER....." Alguma ideia ??

Comment: Não se esqueça que tem de ligar os protocolos do SQL Server no Sql Server Configuration Manager (ponha a Enabled TCP/IP e Named Pipes). Dê uma olhadela neste [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191294.aspx)

Comment: Já tenho o Enabled TCP/IP e o Named Pipes a Enabled, Mas o erro continua..."A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL SERVER  ....... error:40 - Could not open a connection to Sql Server

Comment: Quando é que obtém o erro? Quanto tenta ligar pelos `Management Tools`? Ou pelo seu programa? Que connection string é que está a utilizar? O servidor SQL está a correr?

Comment: Provavelmente este problema deve ser facil de resolve, mas como é a minha primeira vez a instalar um software noutras maquinas, realmente preciso de ajuda..Vou fazer Update da pergunta com mais dados , mas ver se me consegue ajudar !Desde já agradeço a disponibilidade.

Comment: Resolvi o problema instalando o localDB nos outros computadores e alterando a connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um instalador, onde além de instalar a sua aplicação ele instala também o SQL Express 2012 na workstation do usuário.

Você pode criar também um arquivo bat para realizar uma instalação unattended do SQL Server.